# Trigger events with the insertion and deletion of rows in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am using the code below to trigger certain events when rows have been deleted and inserted, the good thing about this code is that it makes a distinction between inserted and deleted rows and thus trigger events for each situation, the only limitation with this is it doesn't work if the first change you make to the workbook is the addition or deletion of a row, but it works fine after that first change.
Anyone know how to fix this problem? Someone suggested a Worksheet_Activate event before the code but i am too inexperienced to figure it out...

First we define a range name (RowMarker =$A$1000)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static lngRow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    If lngRow = 0 Then
    lngRow = rng1.Row
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If rng1.Row = lngRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng1.Row < lngRow Then
        MsgBox lngRow - rng1.Row & " rows removed"
    Else
        MsgBox rng1.Row - lngRow & " rows added"
    End If
    lngRow = rng1.Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module, to be processed (overwrite the existing code event):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    ThisWorkbook.lRow = rng1.row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static lngRow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    If lngRow = 0 Then lngRow = ThisWorkbook.lRow
    If lngRow = 0 Then 'only for the case you copied the code and forgot sheet activating...
        lngRow = rng1.row
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If rng1.row = lngRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng1.row < lngRow Then
        MsgBox lngRow - rng1.row & " rows removed"
    Else
        MsgBox rng1.row - lngRow & " rows added"
    End If
    lngRow = rng1.row
End Sub
```

1.1 Copy this code in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Public lRow As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    lRow = rng1.row
End Sub
```

2. Deactivate the active sheet (go to other one) and activate it (come back). Only first time! When you open the workbook and go to that specific sheet, the event is automatically triggered.
3. Try the solution and send some feedback

`lRow` can be used without the static variable, too, but I tried to keep your initial code as it is, only modifying it to have a reference first time when `Change` event is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your response, as you stated this method works if you open the excel sheet and then switch between sheets but i am wondering is there a solution that does not require this kind of manual change for example i do not want to switch sheets everytime i open my excel, appreciate your help!

Comment: @bagofdoom I am afraid you were not so attentive when read the second issue... **Only first time!** means really **once**, after copying the code. Then, you do not have to wary about nothing. It will work completely automatically. :)

Comment: Yes i understood you only have to switch sheets once and then the code will work after that automatically. But my issue is that what if i close my excel workbook and then open it later, i will still have to switch between sheets to make it work again.

Comment: @bagofdoom Before learning programming, you should learn better reading... :) What does **When you open the workbook and go to that specific sheet, the event is automatically triggered** looks to mean? Not only the code matters in an answer... It will also work if the sheet in discussion is the active one. The event will be triggered, anyhow. You should manually activate the sheet **once in your life**. Then, what will cost you to test this scenario?

Comment: You are saying that you only have to activate it once by switching sheets and then whether you close excel and open it on the active sheet it should work, but it doesnt  work for me, each time i close and open excel i have to switch between sheets to make it work...

Comment: @bagofdoom Then, I will adapt the code to use 'SelectionChange` event... Or place a code line in `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: @bagofdoom Please, test the updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add Workbook event

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.lrow = Sheet1.Range("RowMarker").Row
End Sub
```

Worksheet Event

```vb
Public lrow As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim n as Long
    n = Me.Range("RowMarker").Row - lrow
    lrow = Me.Range("RowMarker").Row
    If n > 0 Then
        MsgBox n & " rows inserted"
    ElseIf n < 0 Then
        MsgBox n & " rows removed"
    End If

End Sub
```